# Execute php script in cron on Openshift

Tags: cron, openshift

I have a PHP 5.4 app setup with Cron 1.4 added.  I need to be able to execute a script, preferably minutely, to send notifications on my site, but I can't to get this to work.

The script is located at:

```
/var/lib/openshift/OPENSHIFT_GEAR_UUID/app-root/runtime/repo/www/components/com_notifications/process.php
```

*OPENSHIFT_GEAR_UUID used to replace actual value**

I've added a file called `notifications` to the `.openshift/cron/minutely/` folder and added the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/www/components/com_notifications/process.php
```

I've tried everything I can think of or find to get this to work.  I've tried removing the curly brackets (I'm not really sure if they're needed).  I've tried `#!/bin/sh` instead.  I've chmodded them to make sure they had the executable right.

The script does work when I load the page up in my browser.  I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift) and it actually does print to the log file so I know the cron is working.  When I `ssh` in and execute the command, it works.  I just can't seem to do it with cron.

Any suggestions or ideas?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I've changed the file to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/www/components/com_notifications/process.php >> ${OPENSHIT_DATA_DIR}/output.log 2>&1
date >> ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/ticktock.log
```

The ticktock.log is being updated every minute, but for some reason, the php script still isn't being called.  I've tried switching to `wget`, which is far from an ideal solution, and calling it from the domain, but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally seems to have worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
php ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}www/components/com_notifications/process.php
```

Since the Enviroment Variables all end with trailing `/`, I removed them from the code to see if it would work properly.  I deleted the `notifications` file and created a new file called `cron`. I think there may be some odd caching that's might cause problems when testing different code.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that something in your php file is not working correctly, try directing the output of your php file to a file in your data directory using >> ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/output.log and see if you are getting some kind of error running it from cron.  Maybe some environment variable or something that it needs is not there.

Comment: so basically `php -f ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/www/components/com_notifications/process.php >> ${OPENSHIT_DATA_DIR}/output.log`?

Comment: Yep, actually might need something more like this to capture errors also: php -f ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/www/components/com_notifications/process.php >> ${OPENSHIT_DATA_DIR}/output.log 2>&1

Comment: Should the output.log folder still be created and empty even if there are no errors cause I'm not getting anything?